# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:];

Tags: objective-c, file-io, exc-bad-access

**I found the answer after I set the bounty. If somebody has some useful comments on my approach (I don't know if it is the 'right' solution) he/she can have the bounty. If you're going to downvote my question, please leve a comment so I can improve future questions.**

I'm currently learning Objective-C with the book `Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X` and it introduces archiving in chapter 10. I (AFAIK) did exactly what the author wants me to do, but when opening a file and thus unarchiving it the app crashes on the line:

```
array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

It says `GDB received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I have only encountered this when accessing an array slot that is out of bounds, and I believe **I** am not doing that. My best guess is that something behind the Cocoa scenes goes wrong, indirectly caused by me. What could this be?
As I said I am currently learning Objective-C (but I know Java), so don't expect me to know every obscure language feature.

The file opening method (`MyDocument.m`):

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSMutableArray *array = nil;
    NSLog(@"data is %@", data);

    @try {
        array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; // line of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        if (outError) {
            NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"The data is corrupted." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
            *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:unimpErr userInfo:d];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    [self setEmployees:array];
    return YES;
}
```

The file saving method (still `MyDocument.m`):

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    [[tv window] endEditingFor:nil]; // tv is my IBOutlet to an NSTableView

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:employees];
}
```

This is the stack trace (Thanks, H2CO3):

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff858da104 in objc_msgSend_vtable13 ()
#1  0x00007fff858dcff5 in objc_getProperty ()
#2  0x00000001000022cf in -[Person name] (self=0x1001d4480, _cmd=0x7fff89d1a790) at /Users/mauritsfriedrichkoelmans/Desktop/RaiseMan1/Person.m:14
#3  0x00007fff86e79674 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] ()
#4  0x00007fff86e7cfb8 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] ()
#5  0x00007fff897e10df in -[NSBinder valueForBinding:atIndex:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] ()
#6  0x00007fff89682aa2 in -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] ()
#7  0x00007fff897e0e75 in -[NSValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] ()
#8  0x00007fff897e0d83 in -[NSTextValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] ()
#9  0x00007fff897e0d30 in -[_NSBindingAdaptor tableColumn:willDisplayCell:row:] ()
#10 0x00007fff896cab00 in -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] ()
#11 0x00007fff896ca306 in -[NSTableView _dirtyVisibleCellsForKeyStateChange] ()
#12 0x00007fff896c9e96 in -[NSTableView _windowChangedKeyState] ()
#13 0x00007fff88ba0d3e in CFArrayApplyFunction ()
#14 0x00007fff89611478 in -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] ()
#15 0x00007fff88ba0d3e in CFArrayApplyFunction ()
#16 0x00007fff89611478 in -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] ()
#17 0x00007fff88ba0d3e in CFArrayApplyFunction ()
#18 0x00007fff89611478 in -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] ()
#19 0x00007fff88ba0d3e in CFArrayApplyFunction ()
#20 0x00007fff89611478 in -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] ()
#21 0x00007fff896c991f in -[NSFrameView _windowChangedKeyState] ()
#22 0x00007fff89611171 in -[NSWindow _setFrameNeedsDisplay:] ()
#23 0x00007fff8960f1d8 in -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] ()
#24 0x00007fff8960f13e in -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] ()
#25 0x00007fff89814401 in -[NSWindowController showWindow:] ()
#26 0x00007fff897e5c5c in -[NSDocument showWindows] ()
#27 0x00007fff899539c1 in -[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:] ()
#28 0x00007fff89953072 in -[NSDocumentController _openDocumentsWithContentsOfURLs:display:presentErrors:] ()
#29 0x00007fff8976eeda in -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] ()
#30 0x00007fff8979346a in -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] ()
#31 0x00007fff897931d4 in -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] ()
#32 0x00007fff89778e45 in -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] ()
#33 0x00007fff89777bed in -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] ()
#34 0x00007fff896486b9 in -[NSApplication sendEvent:] ()
#35 0x00007fff895df6de in -[NSApplication run] ()
#36 0x00007fff895d83b0 in NSApplicationMain ()
#37 0x0000000100001e9b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff660) at /Users/mauritsfriedrichkoelmans/Desktop/RaiseMan1/main.m:13
(gdb)
```

The data object is *not* nil, `NSLog()`ed it.

Comment: Let's start by providing a stack trace.

Comment: Do this before the line you gave NSLog(@"%i",data.length); - I suspect the answer will be 0.

Comment: The information we need is the full code.

Comment: And please see my edit too @H2CO3

Comment: @11684 this is not the stack trace. Type `bt` at the GDB prompt.

Comment: Ah, I always just guessed what a stack trace was. Nobody has ever told me. @H2CO3

Comment: @H2CO3 Person.m:14 is `@synthesize name;` (assuming it means _line_ 14). `name` is just an `NSString`...

Comment: @11684 Thanks. It seems that the `person` object is deallocated at the time its `name` property is accessed. Temporary solution: `retain` it immediately after creation. Permanent solution: track down where it gets released.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but I don't actually create that object. That is done by an `NSArrayController`, and if it has been created, I add it to the `employees` array. I don't release it, too. I only release the array when the current document gets closed (It's a Document based application). I save the `employees` array to a file in the `- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError` method, and retrieve it in `- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError`. Then that Person object is created by an `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. @H2CO3

Comment: So I don't know where to retain it, because everything happens behind the Cocoa scenes...

Comment: Could somebody at least explain to me why it is downvoted?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it myself!

In the book, the `initWithCoder:` method of the Person class (the array I try to unarchive is filled with instances of that class) looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super init];
    name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    expectedRaise = [coder decodeFloatForKey:@"expectedRaise"];
    return self;
}
```

But it had to be:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super init];
    self.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.expectedRaise = [coder decodeFloatForKey:@"expectedRaise"];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Oh, you are not using ARC? That would have also prevented the problem.

Comment: Super call should also be `self = [super init];`

Answer (score 3):

My experience tells me that your `data` object is `nil`

Comment: Will test very quickly. But I did exactly what the author did, I typed it over. At the moment I saw the code I thought: 'why doesn't he handle any errors?' But directly below the code fragment he wrote: 'note that I ignored the error argument. There Will be no errors'. So at least the author doubts this. And how could this create an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I misread the book, he said there will be no errors in the file _saving_ method, this is for opening it. But the data object is not nil.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your save is successful:

```
if (![NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myDictionary toFile:path])
{
    // saving failed for some reason
    return;
}
```

Also make sure the file exists before trying to unarchive it:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    // file does not exist at path (deleted?)
    return;
}
```

Comment: The file exists, because I obtained the data object via Cocoa. (It is a Document based app). But because the bounty expires in one hour: here it is for your second point. That is indeed a good point.